How to provide the HIP kernel for Cycles GPU compute (it is missing)?
This is my first time learning Blender. I've encountered a problem when I switch from Eevee to Cycles. "HIP binary kernel for this graphics card compute capability (11.0) not found."
My GPU is an AMD RX 7600, CPU is a Ryzen 5 5500.

Try using a compute language other than HIP. I don’t know why the kernel for it isn’t there but the easiest thing is just use a different one.

Is this about Linux? If so you probably have to install the missing HIP runtime packages.
